# discord.py the bot doesn't give the role provided upon member join

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to set up this bot event where it would give a role to the member that joins. For some reason, it doesn't give the role, but it doesn't give any error output either.

```
@client.event
def on_member_join(member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="868708006504833034")
  await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
@client.event
def on_member_join(member):
  role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id="868708006504833034")
  await client.add_roles(member, role)
```

## There are a few issues with your code

- in line 2, the function is not async, discord.py events need to be async so replace `def` with `async def`
- in line 3, ids are always ints, so you would make it an int, but you shouldn't even use `discord.utils.get` since you can just do `member.guild.get_role(id)`. Note: id has to be int
- in line 4, client.add_roles is outdated, [it was replaced by member.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful). So you would have to change `client.add_roles(member, role)` to `member.add_roles(role)`

#### So the full updated code would be

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  role = member.guild.get_role(868708006504833034)
  await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Hmm. could you post the full updated code?

Comment: Do you have intents set-up?

Comment: Yeah, I think so.

Comment: well I think so is not gonna work, make sure you have set the members intent to true, official docs on intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html. specially see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#where-d-my-members-go

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
      await member.add_roles(discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=868708006504833034))
```

I think it can work correctly

Answer (score 0):

ID is an integer:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, id=868708006504833034)
```

Try it.